# Double renders after restarting a React web app, how to fix the issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am developing a web app with React.
I need to programmatically restart the app after updating its settings, but should not reload the page.

Here is my code

```js
class App {
  destroy() {
    // rootDom is where <AppComponent /> mount
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.rootDom);
    this.rootDom?.remove();

    this.addons = {} as any;
    delete App.instances[this.appName];
  }

  async restart() {
    this.destroy();
    await this.ready();
    await this.start();
  }
}
```

When I try to run the above code, things seem to be OK. but when I tried to scroll the page, I found double renders, how to fix this issue?

[image: double renders]

Comment: _"I need to programmatically restart the app"_ what does that mean? React apps don't really _start_ other than when the client first loads the page

Comment: If you are using `createRoot` to "start" the app the root created will have an `unmount()` function that you will need to call.

Comment: @Phil it's possible to use react to extend legacy sites, depending on what approach people want to take it might make sense to initialise and dispose of the app multiple times based on events that occur.